# index is out of range, removing item from am array

Tags: java

I'm trying to add the functionality to remove an item from an array via method call but am running into the problem posted in the title.

Heres the instructions:

Write a new method for the ArrayIntList class called remove that takes an integer index and that removes the value at the given index, shifting subsequent values to the left. For example, if a variable called list stores the following values:

```
[3, 19, 42, 7, -3, 4]
```

after making this method call:

"list.remove(1);"
would remove 3 from the array (not this is not specific to just the first value of the array

I tried to implement doing this:

```
    public void remove(int index) {
        int target = index;
        int[] elementDataCopy = new int[size];
        size = elementData.length;
        
        if (index < 0 || index >= size) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid index");
        }
        
        //loop through each value until the index given is == to loop value
        //create a copy of elementData where length is one less and value at 
        //index given is not present
        //each time something is removed, the tracked values decrease by one
        size--;
    
        for(int i = 0; i < elementData.length + 2; i++){
            if (elementData[i] == target){
                continue;
            }else{
                elementDataCopy[i] = elementData[i];
            }
        }
       
    }
``
but get this error:
```

Failed: Index 12 out of bounds for length 12

```
with the numbers differing depending on what input is.

note that elementData is an array of ints and index is an int that is pointing at a point in said array

all help is appreciated, pretty sure this is something basic
```

Comment: Lists and arrays are zero-indexed in most programming languages, including Java. This means that the first element has index `0`, not `1` - and that the last element has index `length - 1`. Trying to take the element at index `12` of an array with 12 elements will fail, because the 12th element of the array has index `11`.

Comment: iterate with the condition `i < elementData.length + 2` will always go out of bounds

Comment: Where do you set size?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this. The big mistake is using `i` for both source and destination indices.  Use a separate one (`k` here) for destination. Only increment the destination index when the copy is made. Once done,
reassign the elementDataCopy to elementData.

```
int k = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < elementData.length; i++) {
    if (i == index) { // skip the one to "delete"
        continue;
    }
    elementDataCopy[k++] = elementData[i];
}
elementData = elementDataCopy;
```

Comment: getting this error: Failed: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0

Comment: It worked for me but I don't have your entire class.  You need to check boundaries before attempting the copy.  If something was length 0, it was empty.

Comment: And remove(1) would remove the 2nd item. Not the first. So remove(0) would remove the first. Lists are 0 based (as was already covered in the comments). You also need to examine how you change size. You reassign it in the method and then decrement it later. This doesn't seem correct. The size is the number of elements that currently exists in the list.